# Razor's engine does not automatically encode HTML tags

Tags: razor, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation, itext, razorengine

To be honest, this is my first time using `asp.net web api` and `Razor`.

I received an asp.net web api solution which uses itextSharp to generate a pdf.
The pdf is generated, but it is showing html tags that were sent with the content via jquery and JSON.

This is how it looks in PDF:

```
<div class="nf-filler-control-border"><div class="nf-filler-control-inner"><div class="ms-r
testate-field"><div
class="ExternalClassD88FE0C0B2A64B1797917A506C26ACA2"><div
class="ExternalClassAD6BB90065794E90B1097577B8697812">Aantal genodigden: 19</div><div
class="ExternalClassAD6BB90065794E90B1097577B8697812">Aantal aanwezig: 15</div><p
class="ExternalClassAD6BB90065794E90B1097577B8697812">Aantal ziek/verlof: 3</p><div
class="ExternalClassAD6BB90065794E90B1097577B8697812"><ol><li>Bij veiligheidsrondgang uitgevoerd op 02/04/13. Veel
gereedschap ligt niet op hun plaats, is onbeheerd achtergelaten, ligt in fietskarren, en zijn bovendien niet ingeschreven in
het register; kasten staan open, ladders niet afgesloten.</li><li>Persoonlijk werkgereedschap blijft gewoon liggen zelf
heeft men de dag erna verlof. = rommel.</li><li>Bij controle stekkers verleng kabels zien we dat de trekontlasting niet
correct gebruikt wordt en dat de insnijdingen te groot zijn. Zie foto's.</li>
<li>Alle communicatie (ziektebriefjes, KV,.....)met HR is nu naar Interleuvenlaan 27A - 3001 Herverlee
(achterzijde personeelsbadge)</li></ol></div></div></div></div></div>
```

this is the piece of code that displays data which is sent via jquery's ajax function: `@Model.Description`
And this is where the Razor engine parses the html template: `return Razor.Parse(template, model);`

Anyone has got any idea how to show the content properly inside the pdf without showing up the html tags on the document?
the html table shows fine, only the data displayed by `@Model.Description` does not show correctly.

---

this is the code:

```
    private  static string GetReport(ToolBoxMeeting tm)
    {
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
            {
                BaseTemplateType = typeof (HtmlTemplateBase<>)
            };

        using (new TemplateService(config))
        {
            string template = @"<html>
                                        <body >
                                        <table >
                                            <tr>
                                                <td'>Description</td>
                                                <td>
                                                        @Model.Description
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table> 

                                        </body>
                                        </html>";

            var model = tm;
            return Razor.Parse(template, model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Inspect the value of `Razor.Parse(template, model)`. I'm guessing you're going to see a bunch of `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: I cannot debug the code since it is showing me an error about System.Security.SecurityException.

can you tell me how can I convert them to proper tags?

Comment: Can you just `Response.Write(Razor.Parse(template, model))`? In not, just throw an exception with that as a string.

Comment: I think it contains the &lt; and &gt; chars.

Comment: I have used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.Description), but still it does not work

Comment: I don't know much about Razor. I'd recommend rewriting your entire question to exclude iTextSharp for now and dedicate it completely to getting Razor's engine to not automatically encode your HTML for you.